# registration_errors hook doesn't show error message

Tags: php, wordpress, user-registration

i customized registration page of wordpress.
I modified function.php in my theme folder to add some registration field and I added the 'registration_error' hook to handle errors.
Here the code of registrion_errors filter:

```
function nuovicampiform_errori( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) 
{
    $errors->add( 'demo_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This is a demo error.'));
    //var_dump($errors);
    if ( empty( $_POST['nome'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['nome'] ) && trim( $_POST['nome'] ) == '' ){
        $errors->add( 'nome_error',__('<strong>ERRORE</strong>: Compilare il campo Nome.', 'localhost' ) );
    }
    if ( empty( $_POST['cognome'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['cognome'] ) && trim( $_POST['cognome'] ) == '' ){
        $errors->add('cognome_error', __('<strong>ERRORE</strong>: Compilare il campo Cognome.', 'localhost' ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['genere'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['genere'] ) && trim($_POST['genere'] ) == '' ){
        $errors->add( 'genere_error', __('<strong>ERRORE</strong>: Selezionare il Genere', 'localhost' ) );
    }
    if ( empty( $_POST['privacy'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['privacy'] ) && trim( $_POST['privacy'] ) == '' ){
        $errors->add( 'privacy_error', __('<strong>ERRORE</strong>: Devi dare l\'autorizzazione al trattamento dei dati', 'localhost' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
add_filter('registration_errors', 'nuovicampiform_errori', 10, 3);
```

Registration works fine and it is aborted if i get an error in a field but the message is not displayed! i get the login_error (with red left border) div empty. $errors array is filled with the correct messages (i did a var_dump)
Why error messages are not displayed!

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it can be usefull to translate messages so that others can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to display error message if user doesn't write name, surname, doesn't select the gender and doesn't accept privacy terms

Answer (score 0):

I solved,
A plugin setting prevented error messages in login page and registration page.